# How to get asp.net return drop down list to return value as int

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

How to get asp.net return drop down list to return value as int

I want to pass the value to a stored procedure as an integer. But the default appears to be as a string which is not what the store procedure is expecting.

Is there a good way to return the list values as ints?

I suspect I can you set the value on the change selection event, is there another way?

Comment: I was looking to get an asp.net control like drop down list to give me an int. But it looks like the selectitem.value is always a string.

I think I will just take the string and convert it in the sproc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DropDownList d = Your_Drop_Down_List;

int i;

if(int.TryParse(d.SelectedValue, out i))
{
  do stuff with i here.
}
else
{
  //selected value did not parse.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `int.Parse(value)`.